# How did my Postgres service start?

Tags: postgresql

When executing:

```
service postgresql-9.5 status"
```

is it possible to see the status of Postgres service whether it started with

`/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pg_ctl -w -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data start`

or with service start command?

Comment: Is this on linux (ubuntu)?

Comment: try `ps aux | grep postgres`